# Can I make the geometry of the first page different from other pages?

Tags: geometry, afterpage

I want to make the top margin in the first page larger than other pages. The code I use is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=8cm,
    hmargin=1in,
}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\afterpage{
    \newgeometry{
        top=3cm
    }
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The output pdf has the same page layout for every page and I don't get what I want. How can I have the different layout for the first page?

Comment: The first page is your title page i  guess? You can always add a negative vertical space. Or use the title page as a separate file and include the pdf. But don't mess around with afterpage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two things to be considered:

First, the `\afterpage` command expands its contents in a group, so changes are reverted unless they are `\global`. The effect of `\newgeometry` is local, so nothing happens when you execute it inside `\afterpage`.

Second, the `\afterpage` command inserts its argument after the *current page* has ended, so if you do `\lipsum\afterpage{<something>}\lipsum`, the `<something>` will be inserted in the page that follows the end of the first `\lipsum` (which is, in this case, past the middle of the document).

To work around these issues I used `\restoregeometry` instead, which is only one token, so it can be easily inserted `\aftergroup`, and I moved the call to `\afterpage` right at the beginning of the document, so it will take effect once the first page ends.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=3cm,
    hmargin=1in,
}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=8cm}
\afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works. Can you explain why the `\aftergroup` command is needed?

Comment: @Ice0cean `\aftergroup` inserts the next token after one `\endgroup` (or `}` or `\egroup`), which is needed here. I added an explanation.